# mongodb replace all instances of certain value for subdocument

Tags: mongodb

My collection (called "workers"):

```
"_id" : "500"
"type" : "Manager",
"employees" : [{
"name" : "bob"
"id" : 101
},{
"name" : "phil"
"id" : 102
}]
```

Goal: for every _id that is a type: Manager AND that contains a subdocument that has an "id" of 102: replace 102 with 202.

Desired End result:

```
"_id" : "500"
"type" : "Manager",
"employees" : [{
"name" : "bob"
"id" : 101
},{
"name" : "phil"
"id" : 202
}]
```

I have tried:

```
db.workers.update({type:'Manager','employees.id':'102'},{$set:{'employees.id':'202'}},{multi:true})
```

I then did the following two things to verify:

```
db.workers.find({type: "Manager", 'employees.id': 102}).count()
```

I get a result of 9.

I also tried this to verify:

```
db.workers.find({$and: [{type: "Manager"},{"employees.id":60}]}).count()
```

This returned 0.

I am pretty confused at this point.  Is my update wrong? is my find wrong? Is it both? Is the '9' result wrong? Is the '0' wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the [`$` positional update](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/positional/#op._S_) operator to update the specific element that matched your query.  Your update is also using values of `'102'` and `'202'` which makes the update try and match strings when those fields are numbers.

Your update should look like this instead:

```js
db.workers.update(
    {type: 'Manager', 'employees.id': 102}, 
    {$set: {'employees.$.id': 202}}, 
    {multi: true})
```